# Set featured image on creating new post

Tags: posts, images, wp-admin, post-thumbnails

I want to set the featured image when creating a new post on the Admin Frontend.
When I installed wordpress I noticed that there's a box to achieve this:
[image: Fresh installation]

But when I try to do this now, I can't find this box:
[image: Current state]

I can still set the featured image via REST-API, but I want to do this in the Admin Frontend too.

I already tried to deactivate all plugins - but that's not the problem.
Did I accidentally change an option for this or why is this box disappeared?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's my fault. I've installed a "blank"-theme to have a blank frontend (because I only use the API) - but I didn't realize that a theme changes something in the Admin Frontend.

By adding this to the functions.php I re-enabled the box:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```